# javascript - for if value is 'in' array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to loop out a list of names and console.logging the values that match. Am I going wrong using (if **value** in **array**)?

```
    for (var i = 0; i < this.state.apiResponse.length ; i++) {

      var selectedChars = this.state.chosenChars
      var returnedChars = this.state.apiResponse[i].name

      console.log(selectedChars)
      console.log(returnedChars)


      // I think i'm making a mistake with this if statement
      if (returnedChars in selectedChars) {
        console.log(this.state.apiResponse[i].name);            
      }
```

The selectedChars array and returned values:

```
["Luke Skywalker", "Han Solo"]

Luke Skywalker
Han Solo
Chewbacca
```

Comment: the `in` operator doesn't do what you seem to think it does. Use `indexOf`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `string.indexOf(substring)`:

```
if (selectedChars.indexOf(returnedChars) !== -1) {
  console.log(this.state.apiResponse[i].name);            
}
```

`string.indexOf(substring)` returns the index of the substring in the string, or `-1` if the substring can't be found. If we check for "anything except -1", we can make sure the `returnedChars` are in the `selectedChars`.

Comment: ah, I had tried using (selectedChars.indexOf(returnedChars)). I wasn't checking it against the !==-1, thanks for clarifying this!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `in` operator. Instead use `indexOf`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.state.apiResponse.length ; i++) {

  var selectedChars = this.state.chosenChars
  var returnedChars = this.state.apiResponse[i].name

  console.log(selectedChars)
  console.log(returnedChars)


  // I think i'm making a mistake with this if statement
  if (selectedChars.indexOf(returnedChars)!==-1) {
    console.log(this.state.apiResponse[i].name);            
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it is not python, it's javascript :)

You can use `indexOf()` method on arrays.

```
  if (selectedChars.indexOf(returnedChars) > -1) {
    console.log(this.state.apiResponse[i].name);            
  }
```

Sorry,, search() is for strings.